# Easy Pivot table for turning columns into rows based on condition

Tags: google-sheets

Is there an easy method for turning a some binary columns into rows based on the value = 1, and then aggregating the total of the aggregated fields.

**Example:**

| Condition_1 | Condition_2 | Condition_3 | agg_1 | agg_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 100 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 100 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 50 | 100 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 50 | 100 |

And have is set to something like:

| Cohort | agg_1 | Agg_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Condition_1 | 50 | 100 |
| Condition_2 | 150 | 300 |
| Condition_3 | 150 | 300 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this:

**Sample data:**

[image]

- In cell **A8** insert this formula to populate the column names: `={"Cohort", D1:E1}`
- In cell **A9** insert this formula to populate the row names: `=transpose(A1:C1)`
- In cell **B9** insert this formula to sum the aggregated fields and drag it to **B11**: `=query(query({index($A$2:$C$5,,match(A9, $A$1:$C$1)),$D$2:$E$5}, "select sum(Col2), sum(Col3) where Col1 = 1", 0), "offset 1", 0)`

In the index section of the formula above, it will create a table which consists of the ***target condition column + agg_1 and agg_2 column***:

**Example:**

[image]

then using the Query function, it will sum the columns **Agg_1** and **Agg_2s** based on the value of the **Condition column**.

### References:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)